# How do I show $f(x+2)-f(x)>2 \forall x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

For the function

> $f(x)=x\cos{\frac{1}{x}}$, $x\geq1$,

How do I show that $f(x+2)-f(x)>2 \forall x$?

Comment: Hmm, did you try to show it's true for $x=1$, so $f(3)-f(1)>2$ and then show the derivative of $f(x+2)-f(x)>0$ for $x>1$ so it must then hold for all $x>1$?  I believe the derivative is $\cos(\frac1{x+2})-\sin(\frac1{x+2}) + \frac1{x}\cos(\frac1x) - \cos(\frac1x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x) = x$

Assume $x > 1$

$f(x+2)−f(x)>2$

$=>$$(f(x+2)-g(x+2))$−$(f(x)-g(x))>0$

Now if we can prove $f-g$ is monotonically increasing we are done.

$f-g$ = $x(Cos(1/x)-1)$

Now we want to prove that the derivative is always positive.

Take derivative we get:

$D(f-g)$ = $-1 + Cos(1/x) + Sin(1/x)/x$

Notice that the derivative is $0$ at $Infinity$

Then, if we can show that the derivative is decreasing we can show that the derivative is positive at $x > 1$.

Take derivative again:

D(D(f-g)) = $-(Cos[1/x]/x^3)$, which gives the desired result.

Done

Comment: $D(f-g)$ is 0 not only at infinity. you can make sure just drawing the graph of $f-g$

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to. $D(f−g)$ is monotonically decreasing from 1 to infinity, therefore I don't think there is another 0 between 1 and infinity.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was considering the whole plane, not just $x \geq 1$. you are right!

Answer (score 2):

First, by the Mean Value Theorem there is an $x_0\in(x,x+2)$ such that $f^\prime(x_0)=\frac{f(x+2)-f(x)}{2}$. But $f^\prime(y)=\frac{1}{y}\sin\frac{1}{y}+\cos\frac{1}{y}$. If we can show that $f^\prime(y)\ge 1$ for all $y\ge 1$, we finish.

Taking $u=1/y$, the last condition is equivalent to show that $u\sin u+\cos u\ge1$ for $u\in(0,1]$. Let $g(u)=u\sin u+\cos u$. Then $g^\prime(u)=u\cos u>0$ for $u\in(0,1]$. Then, $g$ is an increasing function in $(0,1]$. By continuity, this implies that, for $u\in (0,1]$, $g(u)> \lim_{t\to 0^+}g(t)=1$.

Conclusion: $g(u)> 1$ for all $u\in(0,1]$, and this implies $f^\prime(y)< 1$ for all $y\ge 1$. In particular $f^\prime(x_0)< 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos{\frac{1}{x}}=1-\frac{1}{x^22!}+\frac{1}{x^44!}-....$

$x\cos{\frac{1}{x}}=x-\frac{1}{x2!}+\frac{1}{x^34!}-....$

So $(x+2)\cos{\frac{1}{x+2}}=(x+2)-\frac{1}{(x+2)2!}+\frac{1}{(x+2)^34!}-....$

So $f(x+2)-f(x)=2+\{\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{2(x+2)}\}+...$

$=2+\frac{1}{x(x+2)}+...>2$

**NOTE**: As the number of terms in the summation increases  the magnitude of the terms decreases in particular less than the term before and since $x>0$ the terms are always positive .

Comment: The next term is actually negative, i.e., $\dfrac1{4!(x+2)^3} - \dfrac1{4!x^3}$. Hence the argument doesn't work.

Comment: No you are wrong ; just see the difference of the second term and  the third term which you have written it will be greater than $0$ @Leg